# @sentry/react-native with react-native-web -- ErrorUtils is not defined

Tags: react-native, sentry, react-native-web, react-native-sentry

I'm trying to use @sentry/react-native in a project that uses React Native Web.

React Native Web [seems to not define ErrorUtils](https://github.com/necolas/react-native-web/issues/1621), which from what I gather is a React Native function. This is unfortunate as @sentry/react-native seems to depend on it, from what I can tell from the following error output when I try to use it:

`node_modules/@sentry/react-native/dist/js/integrations/reactnativeerrorhandlers.js`

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: ErrorUtils is not defined
    at ReactNativeErrorHandlers._handleOnError (reactnativeerrorhandlers.ts:169:9)
    at ReactNativeErrorHandlers.setupOnce (reactnativeerrorhandlers.ts:52:10)
```

So is there any way for me to somehow swap out the necessary functions before Sentry tries to use them, or some workaround to this issue, or will I have to use the Sentry JS SDK on the web with a `platform.select` or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This was kindly answered on the Sentry Github](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/issues/2829#issuecomment-1432885250)

> This was fixed in [#2808](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/pull/2808). Release 4.14.1 is coming later today (16 Feb 2023). Note that react-native-web is not officially supported. You will need to add [GlohalHandlers and TryCatch](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-react-native/blob/4afbd43555c90534a8c1a4a09800c7aa793d6152/src/js/sdk.tsx#L35) to the integrations to get web errors.